# How to send model data to the cell internally?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I have following code to display data in table view.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? ArticleTalbeViewCell else {
        fatalError("ArticleTableViewCell not found")
    }

    let articleVM = self.articleListVM.articleAtIndex(indexPath.row)
//        cell.viewModel = articleVM
        cell.titlelabel?.text = articleVM.title
        cell.descriptionLabel?.text = articleVM.description
        return cell
    }
}
```

Now, my code with

```
cell.titlelabel?.text = articleVM.title
cell.descriptionLabel?.text = articleVM.description
```

work well.

Is `cell.viewModel = articleVM` a good practice?

Imagine I must set the date to the cell many times? This approach `cell.viewModel = articleVM` will save several lines.

The `UITableViewCell`'s code is below:

```
class ArticleTalbeViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var titlelabel:UILabel?
    var descriptionLabel:UILabel?

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.setupUI()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setupUI() -> () {
        let label1 = UILabel()
        label1.numberOfLines = 0
        let label2 = UILabel()
        label2.numberOfLines = 0
        label2.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        label2.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh, for: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis.vertical)

        titlelabel = label1
        descriptionLabel = label2
        let staview = UIStackView()
        staview.axis = .vertical

        staview.addArrangedSubview(label1)
        staview.addArrangedSubview(label2)
        staview.spacing = 8
        staview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // !important
        self.contentView.addSubview(staview)

        staview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor,constant: 5).isActive = true
        staview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        staview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        staview.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    }
}
```

The `ArticleListViewModel` code is below:

```
struct ArticleListViewModel {
    let articles:[Article]
}

extension ArticleListViewModel {

    var numbeOfSections: Int {
        return 1
    }

    func numOfRowsInSection(_ section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.articles.count
    }

    func articleAtIndex(_ index: Int) -> ArticleViewModel {
        let article = self.articles[index]
        return ArticleViewModel(article)
    }
}

struct ArticleViewModel {
    private let article: Article
}

extension ArticleViewModel {
    init(_ article: Article) {
        self.article = article
    }
}

extension ArticleViewModel {
    var title: String {
        return self.article.title ?? "null"
    }

    var description: String {
        return self.article.description ?? "null"
    }
}
```

The `ArticleList` code is below:

```
import Foundation

struct ArticleList: Decodable {
    let articles: [Article]
}

struct Article: Decodable {
    let title: String?
    let description: String?
    let chines: String?
}
```

How to edit the "cell" code to implement the `cell.viewModel = articleVM`?

Comment: Are you asking how to implement `cell.viewModel = articleVM` or is it good approach?

Comment: @AtalayAsa Yes!

Comment: Hahaha I do not understand what you mean we have two conditions for which question did you give answer yes :)

Comment: I want to know the answer to two questions.

Comment: Have you had chance to take a look my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I do not think giving `cell.viewModel = articleVM` does not change too much thing. Because of you have created **ArticleListViewModel** and **ArticleViewModel** it would be same if you create these vm's for your table view cell. However, I can give you some advices that is used by me while using MVVM approach.
You can add new property inside table view cell then using property observer give a value to it.

```
cell.article = articleVM
```

Therefore, either your `cellForRowAt` method won't be too long and it is almost same like giving your view model to your cell.

```
private var titlelabel:UILabel?
private var descriptionLabel:UILabel?

var article: ArticleViewModel? {
    didSet {
        guard let article = article else { return }
        titlelabel?.text = article.title
        descriptionLabel?.text = article.description
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, your second question is if you have date variable and formatting inside `cellForRowAt` method takes too many spaces and looks ugly. That is why you need to do your business logic inside view model. Your table view cell is only responsible for showing it not to format it. I hope, it is clear for you. If you have any question you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of configuring the `cell` in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method, you must configure your `cell` in the `ArticleTalbeViewCell` itself using the `dataSource` model, i.e.

```
class ArticleTalbeViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    private var titlelabel: UILabel?
    private var descriptionLabel: UILabel?

    //rest of the code...

    func configure(with article: Article) {
        self.titlelabel?.text = article.title
        self.descriptionLabel?.text = article.description
    }
}
```

In the above code,

**1.** There is no need to expose `titlelabel` and `descriptionLabel` outside the `class ArticleTalbeViewCell`. So, mark both of them `private`.

**2.** You just need to call `configure(with:)` method along with the `Article` instance.

**Why method and not a property of type Article?**

There is no need to save the model object inside the `ArticleTalbeViewCell` until and unless it is required somewhere else after the `cell` is configured once.

In `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method, you need to simply call `configure(with:)` method on your `cell` along with the `article` instance at that particular `indexPath`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? ArticleTalbeViewCell else {
        fatalError("ArticleTableViewCell not found")
    }

    let article = self.articleListVM.articleAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    cell.configure(with: article)
    return cell
}
```

Also, I don't think there is any need to create a separate `ArticleViewModel`. It is not doing anything special. It's just an extra wrapper on `Article`.

You can simply return `Article` type from `articleAtIndex(_:)` method in `extension ArticleListViewModel`, i.e

```
func articleAtIndex(_ index: Int) -> Article {
    let article = self.articles[index]
    return article
}
```

**Why configuration in custom `UITableViewCell`?**

This is because your `tableView` might contain multiple custom `UITableViewCells`. Adding the configuration of all the `cell` in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` will make the code hefty and unable to read. Its better that the `cell` specific configuration is handled by the `cell` itself instead of the `ViewController`.